# Materialize collapsible not expanding right

Tags: jquery, materialize

It works fine if the html is already present but when I add the html dynamically it doesn't work at all. I tried initializing it $('.collapsible').collapsible(); and it expands sometimes but not always.

```
  $(document).on('click', '.controls .add-step', function(e) {
    var addto = $(this).next().find(".collapsible");
    var newIn = '<li class=""> <div class = "collapsible-header" ><i class = "addaction material-icons ">add</i></div><div class = "collapsible-body"><p>This is text</p></div></li>';
    var newInput = $(newIn);
    $(addto).append(newInput);
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ykpLne4o/

Comment: I am absolutely baffled by your code. I'd suggest breaking it down into a simpler example.

Comment: @SeanDoherty https://jsfiddle.net/10bzodce/ this works?

Comment: when you're having a problem like this, it can be a good idea to break it down into it's simplest form - you've got 3 buttons in your example, and 4 areas that do things when clicked, and lines and lines of code - I personally don't have time to sift through all that to see where the error is. What I can fix is pretty much any problem you have with the collapsible component, but it's buried so deep I don't know where to begin.

Comment: @SeanDoherty now https://jsfiddle.net/xpbnomhz/ ?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. The 'add step' button creates a collapsible header (which is the part of a collapsible that triggers the expand/contract), but no content - nothing in collapsible-body. And the header - the bit that triggers said expand - is linked to a function that removes itself! You'd need to explain what this thing is supposed to do, step by step as if speaking to a child.

Comment: @SeanDoherty The Add step creates a collapsible header without any text in it. You click the "add" on the header to create it. This collapsible header does not work on and off if I keep adding text to it. I removed the remove button it's not relevant here https://jsfiddle.net/q26esyrj/

Comment: Ok this is clearer now. @csgabriella is correct - you need to remove the add click handler from the header. Do you see the problem? You can't have an element with two types of click listener attached (one to expand/contract, one to append content), and not have issues with propagation. Any one click is going to trigger an expand, or a contract, or an add. You need to separate them. And you don't need to keep re-initialising collapsible - it should run once, when the collapsible is created. And why does this component have to be a collapsible? Why can't it just be a div?

Comment: @SeanDoherty I removed the add click handler but I still have the same issue https://jsfiddle.net/pv0Lbm8a/

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is that it is constantly clicking on the `addaction` and it also triggers your collapse method. Try separating your icons into a div, that are not part of the header maybe?

Comment: This works fine if the HTML is not dynamically added